# Explicitly defaulted and deleted constructor: is there any similar functionality available in VS2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, constructor, copy-constructor

In VS2012, the "Explicitly defaulted and deleted special member functions" feature (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#Explicitly_defaulted_and_deleted_special_member_functions , http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2346.htm) isn't yet available (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx ).  Is there any workaround to use such functionality, even if very very verbose?
In practice, can I translate this

```
struct NonCopyable {
    NonCopyable() = default;      
    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable&) = delete;                
    NonCopyable & operator=(const NonCopyable&) = delete;    
};
```

to something with the same functionality, but without using `default` and `delete`? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, those features are not available yet.

However, you can do this:

```
struct NonCopyable {
    // ...

private:      
    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable&);
    NonCopyable & operator=(const NonCopyable&);
};
```

By just declaring the *copy-constructor* and the *copy-assignement-operator* (no definition) as private you make them not usable. So it as the effect you want to.

A good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2173764/1394283

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you want to create a non-copyable class. C++11 introduces `delete`able functions to easily provide this functionality while in pre-C++11 you can achieve the same through:

- Declare the copy constructor and copy assignment operator as `private` and
- Do not provide any definition for both.

---

**Good Read:**
[Non-copyable Mixin](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Non-copyable_Mixin)

Comment: I read in the link you provide that the default constructor is declared and defined as protected. Why not public?