# Why to delete operator= for noncopyable type?

Tags: c++, c++11

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173746/how-do-i-make-this-c-object-non-copyable) the solution is to delete Copy CTOR and assignment operator. I don't understand why you need to disable assignment operator? It can be non-copyable but still assignable, right?

The same thing happens when you define a singleton class. Why you need to disable the assignment if you have only one instance? :)

Comment: In your own words, what is your understanding of an object that is assignable, but non-copyable? What would you want to happen in that situation?

Comment: You would still copy the thing on the right-hand side, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would allow some kind of proxy-copy like this:

```
NotCopyable a, b;
b = a; // Made a copy of a
```

It is pretty unlikely that you do not want copy construction but copy assignment. Move assignment would be a different deal of course, see e.g. `std::unique_ptr`.

Singleton is basically the same. Why allow the self assignment? That just does not make sense.

Comment: But in this case `b = a` is not a copy construction, right? If it would be `NotCopyable b = a;`, it would we copy construction, right?

Comment: @Narek Correct. But there expected effect is so similar that one does not really make sense without the other. At least I cannot imagine a realistic object where this would make sense.

Comment: Agree. I just think that copy assignment in the answer is not the correct term to use. It is just and assignment.

Comment: @Narek Actually, "copy assignment operator" is the term the C++ standard uses for some member `A &operator=(const A&);` of some `class A`, and `a = b;` as in my example is a called a copy assignment if it invokes a copy assignment operator. (The standard allows it to take a couple of different forms, but the above is by far the most common one.)

Comment: Ok thanks. I guess I need to check why standard calls copy assignment instead of assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, something which is not copyable is not assignable either. I would be hard pressed to invent a real life example where copying is disallowed, but assigning is OK.

On a side note, there is lot's of examples for something to be non-assignable, but copyable.

Answer (score 0):

Both copy construction and copy assignment are considered to be copying.