# C++ Error: use of deleted function during constructor call of custom class

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-errors, systemc

I have a custom class `producer` which inherits from SystemC class `sc_module`:

```
class producer: public sc_module {
    public:
        int counter;
        sc_in<bool> clock;
        sc_out<msg> out;
        int speed;

        producer(sc_module_name name, int speed) : 
            sc_module(name), 
            speed(speed) 
        {
            SC_HAS_PROCESS(producer);
            SC_METHOD(produce);

            sensitive << clock.pos();
            counter = 0;
        }

        void produce() {
            ...
        }

};
```

Later in the SystemC `sc_main`-class I want to put a bunch of objects in a `std::vector<producer>`:

```
std::vector<producer> producers;
for(int i = 0; i < numIn; i++){
    producers.at(i) = producer("Producer " + i, genSpeed); // <- Here the error occurs
}
```

And here is the compiler error:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘producer& producer::operator=(producer&&)’
         producers.at(i) = producer("Producer " + i, genSpeed);
                                                             ^
dist.cpp:103:7: note: ‘producer& producer::operator=(producer&&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class producer: public sc_module {
       ^~~~~~~~
```

Why does the error occur? How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure  the produer / sc_module class is copyable, I have the suspicion that `producers.at(i) = producer("Producer " + i, genSpeed);` is trying to copy-assign a non-copyable type, which is resulting in your error.

Comment: @Gio Well I assume that has something todo with the parent class `sc_module`. How can I find out if its copyable? [Here](http://www.lysium.de/docs/systemc-2.2/docs/html/classsc__core_1_1sc__module.html)  is the class reference...

Comment: Are sc_in<> and sc_out <> movable?

Comment: @ShyamalDesai I don´t think so. Here is the class reference of [`sc_in<>`](https://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lablasso/docs/SystemC2.0.1/html/classsc__in.html)

Comment: You class is copyable if it has a copy constructor. *Usually if a copy constructor is not defined in a class, the compiler itself defines one. *(A specific class definition might specify it as non-copyable, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173746/how-do-i-make-this-c-object-non-copyable)). ps. your link does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I our final solution we used `std::shared_ptr` and `std::vector`:

```
using sharedProducerPointer = std::shared_ptr<producer>;
std::vector<sharedProducerPointer> producers;

//bind producers and distributor to input signals
for(int i = 0; i < numIn; i++) {
    std::string stringProducersName = "producer_" + std::to_string(i);
    const char* charProducersName = stringProducersName.c_str();

    sharedProducerPointer prod = sharedProducerPointer(new producer(charProducersName, genSpeed, numOut));
    prod->out.bind(inputSignals.at(i));
    dist.inputMsg.at(i).bind(inputSignals.at(i));
    prod->clock(inClock);

    producers.push_back(prod);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Copy construction and assignment are disabled for `sc_module`s to implement/preserve SystemC elaboration semantics.

You should use `sc_vector` to create collections of `sc_object`s. It was created specifically to address this type of design problems.

Answer (score 2):

`producer` doesn't have a move assignment operator.  By the looks of things, probably because `sc_module` doesn't have one.

You have other problems:

```
std::vector<producer> producers;
for(int i = 0; i < numIn; i++){
    producers.at(i) ....
}
```

This creates an empty vector of `producers`, and then assigns to the first element of that vector.  The problem is that there *is* no such element, and because you are using `at`, you will get an exception.

Conveniently, you can fix both problems at once with:

```
std::vector<producer> producers;
for(int i = 0; i < numIn; i++){
    producers.emplace_back("Producer " + i, genSpeed);
}
```

This creates an empty vector, and then constructs a series of new `producer`s at the end of it.  This does depend on you having a working move constructor.  If you don't have a working move constructor, I think you are rather stuck.

This still won't work, because you will get producers called "Producer ", "roducer ", "oducer ", etc.  Adding an integer to a character string literal will just return a pointer to the n'th character of the literal.  What you need is to make the literal be a `std::string` literal, and convert the integer to text.

```
    producers.emplace_back("Producer "s + std::to_string(i), genSpeed);
```

Comment: Your final solution does not work : `error: no matching function for call to ‘producer::producer(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int&)’`. Maybe because producers `name` attribute is of type [`sc_module_name`](http://www.lysium.de/docs/systemc-2.2/docs/html/classsc__core_1_1sc__module__name.html)... For other `sc_module` classes something like `"name" + i` (with `i` is in integer) does work, but with `producers.emplace_back("Producer " + i, genSpeed);` I get the error `error: use of deleted function ‘producer::producer(producer&&)’`