# Implementing a non-copyable C++ class

Tags: c++, constructor

In Visual Studio 2019, I am trying, without success, to implement the technique for making a class non-copyable shown for C++11, and later, at the accepted answer at [*How do I make this C++ object non-copyable?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173746/how-do-i-make-this-c-object-non-copyable).

My class is,

```
class Foo {

public:
    Foo();
    Foo(std::string name);
    ~Foo();

    std::string m_name;

    static std::int32_t s_counter;

public:
    Foo(const Foo& inFoo) = delete;
    Foo& operator=(const Foo& inFoo) = delete;
};
```

The definition code is,

```
std::int32_t Foo::s_counter = 0;

Foo::Foo(void)
{
    Foo::s_counter++;
    std::cout << "Foo constructor.  Count = " << Foo::s_counter << std::endl;
}

Foo::Foo(std::string name)
{
    Foo::s_counter++;
    m_name = name;
    std::cout << "Foo " << m_name << " constructor.  Count = " << Foo::s_counter << std::endl;
}

Foo::~Foo()
{
    Foo::s_counter--;
    std::cout << "Foo destructor.  Count = " << Foo::s_counter << std::endl;
}
```

It is used in,

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    std::vector<Foo> fooVector;

    {
        Foo myFoo1{ Foo() };
        fooVector.push_back(std::move(myFoo1));

        Foo myFoo2{ Foo("myFoo2") };
        fooVector.push_back(std::move(myFoo2));
    }

    if (Foo::s_counter < 0) {

        std::cout << "Foo object count = " << Foo::s_counter << std::endl;
    }

    std::cin.get();
}
```

in which I have intentionally scoped the definition of `myFoo1` and `myFoo2` so as to get object count feedback.

When the copy constructor and assignment constructor are made `public`, as shown, the compile error is "C2280   'Foo::Foo(const Foo &)': attempting to reference a deleted function". When they are made private, the compile error is "C2248   'Foo::Foo': cannot access private member declared in class 'Foo'".

I believe I am misinterpreting something in the original SO answer, but I cannot see what it is.

Comment: I don't get it. You've tried to make the object non-copyable. Then you tested it by attempting a copy. The copy failed, as desired. Then you tried a different approach. Success again. What's the problem/question?

Comment: Those errors are the expected result of trying to copy a non-copyable class.

Comment: Don't forget that what you're seeing is, by definition, (usually), correct. So by extension it's what we're all expecting. So, if you were expecting something else instead, you're going to have to tell us what that is. Only then can we tell you why your expectation is wrong.

Comment: Can you explain your use of `std::move`?  Your class is not movable. In case it is not clear, the error message comes from the `push_back` line which attempts to copy the object into the vector. (the other comments/answers seem to have overlooked this)

Comment: It would improve the question to show the full error message which will make it apparent which line caused the error

Comment: BTW it is simpler to use `fooVector.emplace_back();` and `fooVector.emplace_back("myFoo2");` if the intent is to get objects in the vector

Answer (score 6):

Everything's working as expected.

Your code attempts two copies, and both approaches you took to making the class non-copyable succeeded. You can see that, because you got compilation errors.

If you didn't intend to attempt copies in this testcase, it could be these lines:

```
Foo myFoo1{ Foo() };
Foo myFoo2{ Foo("myFoo2") };
```

Prior to C++17, those were copy-initialisations. If that's not what you intended, and you're pre-C++17, then you should change them to:

```
Foo myFoo1{};
Foo myFoo2{"myFoo2"};
```

… or a good old-fashioned:

```
Foo myFoo1;
Foo myFoo2("myFoo2");
```

Meanwhile, your `push_back`s definitely copy because, though you wrote `std::move`, your class isn't moveable (has no move constructor) so the `std::move` actually does nothing.

So:

1. Attempt to copy object
2. Copy is being prevented

All as it should be.

Comment: since C++17 `Foo myFoo1{ Foo() };` is exactly identical to `Foo myFoo1{};`, and similarly for the `myFoo2` line, so those suggestions would make no difference

Comment: Isn't `std::move()` as part of the `push_back()` argument supposed to prevent a copy from being created, and merely move the object into the `std::vector`?  If that is not the case, then I do not understand the reason for `std::move()` use in the recommendation in the referred to answer.

Comment: The problem I am having is that more `Foo` objects are being deleted than constructed, i.e., `Foo::s_counter` is negative just before `main()` exits.

Comment: @user34299 No, that is a common misconception. `std::move` just makes the name of a variable into an rvalue, so that it can bind to the rvalue ref argument in a move constructor. In other words, it "makes it possible to move". It doesn't actually move anything. Indeed, how could it? You did not specify any instructions for moving in your class. Should review move semantics in your book.

Comment: @user34299 _"The problem I am having is that more Foo objects are being deleted than constructed, i.e., Foo::s_counter is negative just before main() exits"_ Your question didn't say anything about this at all

Comment: @user34299 There is no `std::move` mentioned in the other question you refer to  (which is to be expected, since it is from 2010 , before move semantics were added to the language)

Comment: And that. `std::move` is not found on that entire page even once....

Comment: I do not know what semantics to review.  I was following the example in the referred to post and am trying to understand it with my own code, without success.

Comment: I just told you! Read the relevant chapter about move semantics in your book.

Comment: @user34299 you say "I do not understand the reason for std::move() use in the recommendation in the referred to answer."  but the referred to answer does not recommend std::move or even mention it at all  , you are making no sense

Comment: What relevant chapter in what book?

Comment: Okay I think we're being taken for a bit of a ride. I'm out...